# Variable type hints are not validated inside function

Tags: python, type-hinting

When you execute this code:

```py
from typing import Dict

bar: Dict[int, int, int] = dict()
```

an exception `TypeError` with a message `Too many parameters for typing.Dict; actual 3, expected 2` is raised. But when you define the variable inside a function:

```py
from typing import Dict

def foo():
    bar: Dict[int, int, int] = dict()

foo()
```

no exception is raised this time. Is this an expected behavior or a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is intended behavior and is defined at [PEP 526 -- Syntax for Variable Annotations #Runtime Effects of Type Annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#runtime-effects-of-type-annotations).

> Annotating a local variable will cause the interpreter to treat it as a local, even if it was never assigned to. Annotations for local variables will not be evaluated:
>
> ```py
> def f():
>     x: NonexistentName  # No error.
> ```
>
> However, if it is at a module or class level, then the type will be evaluated:
>
> ```
> x: NonexistentName  # Error!
> class X:
>     var: NonexistentName  # Error!
> ```

In addition, [PEP 563 -- Postponed Evaluation of Annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) defines that using `from __future__ import annotations` with python 3.7+ prevents these annotations from being evaluated.

> This PEP proposes changing function annotations and variable annotations so that they are no longer evaluated at function definition time. Instead, they are preserved in __annotations__ in string form.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Dict

bar: Dict[int, int, int] = dict()  # no errors
```

Comment: As for *why* local annotations aren't evaluated, remember that the annotation itself can be arbitrary code, not just a type hint (though non-type-hint uses are deprecated). As such, it would be an exception to evaluate the annotation in a function definition when no other code inside the function is evaluated. PEP 563 makes it a moot point by specifying that *no* annotations will be evaluated, either at definition or call time: annotations become implicit `str` literals that will only be evaluated if you do so explicitly.